# RDF, is it valid to have a single rdf:Statement with multiple rdf:predicate triples attached?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, linked-data, reification

As per subject, Is it valid to assert a single `rdf:Statement` with multiple `rdf:predicate` triples attached to it?

Background: I'm trying to build inferred triples by means of simple rules based on `SPARUL` (ie, `INSERT <inferred triples> WHERE <preconditions>`). In my dataset, I have reified statements based on the `rdf:` vocabulary, and it makes sense to make inferences like:

```
?stmt rdf:predicate ?p; ?p rdfs:subPropertyOf ?p1 => 
  => a statement with rdf:predicate ?p1 is also asserted.
```

The purpose of such inference is mainly vocabulary mapping: people searching with the vocabulary defining `?p1` would also find statements stated by people using the vocabulary where `?p` is defined (eg, `skos:prefLabel(?p) rdfs:subPropertyOf schema:name(?p1)`).

I can't find any documentation that states a statement can only have one `rdf:predicate`, or the opposite. It seems to me that one predicate only would be the cleaner option, however, if that was the case, I would need to duplicate almost all of the existing statement (including additional triples like provenance or significance score) and use `?p1` as the predicate for the new one.

If, instead, I simply add an `rdf:predicate` to the existing one, the implied semantics would be: "there are two which differ by predicate only" and all queries searching for `?p` or `?p1` should work without problems, but I'm not sure I'm not missing anything.

Actually, one thing I can see is that a reified statement count couldn't be based on counting triples like `?s a rdf:Statement`, but that doesn't seem to be a big deal in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer with the information I gather from the Semantic Web group on Facebook (Many thanks to those who contributed).

The common practice is that one reified statement represents one statement only. The interpretation I proposed doesn't work well with the fact that one URI should represent one entity only.

Besides, one can deduce such the unicity from the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema#ch_statement) (emphasis on the definite article is mine):

*The predicate of an RDF statement is the instance of rdf:Property identified by **the** predicate of the triple.*

Moreover, it's unlikely that frameworks like Jena would work well with my approach.

So, definitely not a good idea, I'll go with duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

in this case, I think one could easily do vocabulary mapping by simply stating that `<p>` is equivalent to `<p1>` using owl:sameAs.

the whole reification thing in RDF is woefully underspecified - but there is the conventional use that the reified statement refers to an actual instance of a triple (not multiple, as would be the case when having multiple predicates)

Comment: thanks, I also think it's common to have a 1-1 mapping. Re: `owl:sameAs`, actually we usually have multiple mapping cases (`rdfs:subPropertyOf`, `owl:equivalentProperty`, `owl:inverseOf`)